# How dangerous is it for me to leave a Cloud Function exposed to the public?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that must be exposed to the public, because I need to call the cloud function from an iOS shortcut. [Oauth2.0 is a limitation of iOS shortcuts right now](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/api-limitations-apd891a6c84e/ios). [I tried for 2 hours to exchange a self-signed JWT for a Google-signed ID token](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) but was not able to figure it out.

How dangerous is it for me to leave this cloud function exposed to the public? I understand a bad actor could find this end point and hit it repeatedly to drive up my costs, but would restricting the number of instances to 1-2 prevent that?

Is there anything else I can do to increase security? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a Band-Aid, while you implement real security (authorization), add a query parameter and check the value `https://example.com/?mysecret=123456`. Return a 403 or 404 if the value check fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the max instance to 1 or 2, you will prevent the high cost, but your service will be unvailable for legit requests. So, the user experience will be terrible.

It's hard to protect your service against bad actors. One solution can be to add a load balancer in front of your Cloud Functions and to use Cloud Armor, a waf, on top of it. If you detect bad actors IPs, you can deny them in Cloud Armor.

Comment: Hi @guillaume blaquire, thanks for the response. I should have added more context in my original post. This service is intended only for my personal use. I am exporting data from my phone via automated iOS shortcuts and using cloud functions to push that data into another API as I can't do it directly from shortcuts. I did some additional research and found that I can use a CF to shut down billing if my costs exceed a set budget. Do you think this would be appropriate for my use case?

Comment: Still applies unfortunately. Even if the URL for the function isn't "exposed" anywhere, it's likely to be found and hit just because. You can of course test it out by publishing one that just write something quick to stdout, and limit the instances to 1 or 2 just to see. And watch how fast it starts getting hit. You'll see it in the logging when it gets hit.

Comment: What else would you recommend I do to increase security in this scenario?